# .Mht issue - Blank Page

Tags: uipath, mhtml

*Context: read a table from a body’s email. For that a use this methode (Save email as a .mht, then extract data with web data scraping activity)

I used this method many time, and still working. But, recently I start a new process and when i tried this method some mails appear as a “Blank Page”

Any idea? xD

The only thing I spotted is that the working mails have this code in the footer and others dont have it:

[Working Mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWbBm.png)

[No Working Mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J30Fp.png)

Comment: Maybe that's just a plain text email without any html. Search for a section named Content-Type: text/plain. Can you find your table there?

Comment: @WolfgangRadl Yes, this section exist for both of them (working and not working).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't rely on emails always following standards (see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1521 for more details). In an ideal world, you should encounter messages with `multipart/alternative`, essentially giving you two sections:

1. `text/html` with a formatted (html) message along with a table in your case,
2. `text/plain` containing plain text, allowing any reader to interpret that email (even without html support -- think of showing emails in your command prompt/terminal).

Only because there are standards does not mean people will follow them. You will see messages without the second part, incorrect content types, and much more.

Browsers seems to rely on the first part -- `text/html`. If that part is absent, nothing may be displayed at all (note that the results may differ from browser to browser, and different content types may yield different results -- I tested this using `multipart/mixed` on Chromium).

Moving forward with UiPath, there are the following options:

- Open the MHT file in a different application, for example Mozilla Thunderbird (you may want to rename them to `eml` first). Use Desktop Automation to rename and open a file, then extract your data as desired.
- Use the [Read Text File](https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/read-text-file) activity as a backup in case your browser displays an empty page. You might need to use regular expressions to get the desired section (text/plain), but I'd recommend using a framework such as [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) (available as a NuGet package, so integrating it into UiPath should be easy).

In any case you'll need to parse a plain text representation of the table, potentially turning it into a `DataTable` object, which includes:

- Detecting start and end of table,
- Splitting rows (e.g. when a NewLine character is encountered),
- Splitting cells (tab chars, or separator characters).

Unless you know precisely which formats to expect, this can be challenging.

Comment: Thank you very for your help! I choosen the second way, I parsed as a simple text with regex (0 fun). But thank to you I understand now why <3